# How should I send a dictionary by multipart/form-data in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

I have following complex dictionary:

```
    {
      "platform" : "ios",
      "data" : {
        "films" : [0],
        "about" : "",
        "is_voluntary" : true,
        "items" : [{
          "idx" : 0,
          "dates" : [
            "2020-09-23"
          ],
        "timelines" : [
          "11:00"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "language" : "en"
  },
  "app_version" : "2.1.0"
}
```

My server side requires me to send above data using `multipart/form-data`. I barely understand this format, but here is my try using Alamofire:

```
 var initParams: [String: Any] = ....
 for (key, param) in initParams {
        if let array = param as? [String] {
            for item in array {
                if let data = item.data(using: .utf8) {
                    multipartData.append(data, withName: key)
                }
            }
        } else {
            if let data = "\(param)".data(using: .utf8) {
                multipartData.append(data, withName: key)
            }
        }
    }
```

`multipartData` is Alamofire's object from `Alamofire.upload()` function. But, anyway, above does not work. My server side tells that there is no `data` in my scheme. Where am I wrong? How to properly convert any object to prepare it for `form-data`? Note: `JSONSerialization.data` function does not work also.

Answer (score 1):

It's something like the below code example, I didn't see the full dictionary so you can see the example and do it,

```
{
   "data": {
      "is_voluntary": true
   }
   "app_version": "1.2.3"
}
```

swift code:

```
static func YourMethodName(app_version: String, , completion:@escaping (Bool)->Void) {
  var headers: HTTPHeaders!
  headers = [
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Your token",
        "Accept": "application/json"
             ]
  let url = "Your URL"
                
   AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multiPart) in
        
   multiPart.append(Data("\(app_version)".utf8), withName: "app_version")
   multiPart.append(Data("\(true)".utf8), withName: "data[is_voluntary]")
        
  }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url, method: .post, headers: headers).responseDecodable { (response:`enter code here` DataResponse<UserResponse>) in
   switch response.result {
          case .success(let userResponse):
                 // success data
          case .failure(_):
                 // failure data
          }
                    
   completion(response.response?.statusCode == 200)
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe data[is_voluntary] should be data.is_voluntary?

Comment: yes this part is the attribute you should send with this key.
multiPart.append(Data("\(data.is_voluntary)".utf8), withName: "data[is_voluntary]")